# extract associative array within an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [s_id] => 4
            [si_id] => sec_1
            [d_id] => dep_4
            [s_name] => sec1
            [s_location] => LA
            [s_visibility] => yes
            [s_created_date] => 1273639343
            [s_last_updated_date] => 1273639343
            [s_created_by] => someone
            [s_last_updated_by] => everyone
        )

)
```

now i want to extract array[0] into an array... means i want this

```
Array
(
            [s_id] => 4
            [si_id] => sec_1
            [d_id] => dep_4
            [s_name] => sec1
            [s_location] => LA
            [s_visibility] => yes
            [s_created_date] => 1273639343
            [s_last_updated_date] => 1273639343
            [s_created_by] => someone
            [s_last_updated_by] => everyone

)
```

how do i get above results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
$newArray = $oldArray[0];
```

This will create a **new** array with the same key-value pairs.

If you do not want to create a new array and want the new array to **refer** to the existing array in the `$oldArray` you can do:

```
$newArray = &$oldArray[0];
```

Any changes made to `$newArray` will also change `$oldArray` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.is it not possible by refernecing?

Comment: No need to add another answer... `$newArray = &$oldArray[0];`

Answer (score 0):

See this it may useful for you,

```
$sss = array () ;
$sss['sadness']['info'] = "some info";
$sss['sadness']['info2'] = "more info";
$sss['sadness']['value'] = "value";
$sss['happiness']['info'] = "some info";
$sss['happiness']['info2'] = "more info";
$sss['happiness']['value'] = "value";
$sss['peace']['info'] = "some info";
$sss['peace']['info2'] = "more info";
$sss['peace']['value'] = "value";

print_r($sss['sadness']);
echo "<br>";

print_r($sss);
echo "<br>";
```

Output 1 :

```
Array ( [info] => some info [info2] => more info [value] => value )
```

Output 2 :

```
Array ( [sadness] => Array ( [info] => some info [info2] => more info [value] => value ) [happiness] => Array ( [info] => some info [info2] => more info [value] => value ) [peace] => Array ( [info] => some info [info2] => more info [value] => value ) )
```